# Efficiently creating heat maps in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, maps, data-visualization, heatmap, pushpin

I'm working a project which uses PHP to retrieve data from a MySOL database and is supposed to be parsed and displayed real-time as a heat-map in WP7.

Some queries return 5000+ POIs with data (latitude, longitude, values etc....). I've searched and tried implementing some examples I found but ran into some memory usage problems because of the amount of data being visualized.

My question is: What is the best way to display that quantity of data, as heat maps, efficiently on a WP7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, the best way is converting your POIs into tile images (either completely offline, or by writing a server-side code that queries your MySQL and builds the PNGs), and then overlay your tiles atop of the map. BTW, PHP is not the best tool for such tasks.

See this article: [Adding Tile Overlays to the Map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681902.aspx)

Comment: Soonts, thanks for your answer. You mentioned that PHP is not the best tool for such tasks. Then what is?

Comment: @Alex, because of my background, I'd choose between C# and C++. AFAIK, Java should work just as good. IMO any full-featured programming language with stable and efficient image processing libraries should do the job.